# Memoir class and subsection titles

Tags: fonts, sectioning, memoir

I've been through all types of answers but couldn't make it work:
I use memoir class,  `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`

My running heads are correct, but the section titles are smallcaps (and small!) although subsection titles are bigger and no smallcaps!

How can I get a consistant section/subsection/subsub font size and type?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, twoside, openright, oldfontcommands, 12pt]{memoir}

\title{TITLE ONE}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxtocdepth{paragraph}


\begin{document}
\maketitle            

\frontmatter     

\mainmatter            
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapterstyle{dash}
\pagestyle{companion}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setsecheadstyle{\scshape\large\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\scshape\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\itshape\raggedright}
\setparaheadstyle{\itshape\small \raggedright}
%%%% has to be after frontmater????

\part{part one} 
\chapter{chapter one}
\section{section one}
\subsection{sub section one}
\subsubsection{sub sub section one}
\paragraph{paragraph one}
\backmatter
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, can you show us a [small but compilable code example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) that lets us reproduce that off behaviour?

Comment: Please clarify by: (1) providing some code for us; (2) explaining further what "consistant" means (i.e., a hierarchy that goes from bigger to smaller, or always the same size. Note that, for what it's worth, (humanities) books published by the University of Chicago Press often use small caps for 'sections' and plain Roman text for 'subsections', which does result in subsections looking 'bigger'. (I'm not convinced it looks very good, but others may disagree.)

Comment: Ok thanks; I guess something is going wrong / weird by default. I had to change one by one \setsecheadstyle for each level (section, sub, subsub, paragraph). You are right, by default subsections titles are in plain roman, but the size is very large...